# show and ng-show is not helping out for below div

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

when clicked on a button there should be a div to be shown that "Are u sure, u want to delete"
else other div should be shown.
i am trying either ways using ng-show or show()

```html
<button
    class="button-default button-m panel-heading-margin"
    type="button"
    ng-if="!$last"
    ng-click="deleteButton();"
>
    <i class="icon16 icon-delete v-sub di-block mr-0"></i>
</button>
<div class="modal-footer mt-10 p-0">
    <div
        id="deleteview"
        class="bg-gray-light row"
        ng-show="$scope.displayModal"
    >
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <h4 class="p-15 text-left">
                You are going to <b>Delete</b> the <b>Mapping</b> you have
                selected. Are you sure you want to continue?
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="pt-25 text-right pr-5">
                <button class="button-cancel button-m">Cancel</button>
                <button id="deletesinglemap" class="button-m button-primary">
                    Delete
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="addview" class="pull-right p-20" ng-hide="$scope.displayModal">
        <span class="button-cancel" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</span>
        <button id="addmapping" class="button-m button-primary" type="button">
            Add
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```js
$scope.slideUpModal = function () {
    $scope.displayModal = true;
    $("#deleteview").show();
    $("#addview").hide();
};
```

when clicked on a button there should be a div to be shown that "Are u sure, u want to delete"
else other div should be shown.
i am trying either ways using ng-show or show()

Comment: The first red flag is your use of `$scope` in your template. Your template already starts in the context of your scope. Since you also use `$last`, am I correct to assume this is inside an ngRepeat? Your "controller" example is also insufficient. A plunkr or similar MRE would go a long way in helping debug this.